# jquery ajaxRequest returns null when posting to a servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

For the life of me I can't figure out what's going on. I have a servlet that I am 
posting data to, but everytime I try to post my ajax data to the servlet I just keep getting 
that the data is null.

Here's my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'servletURL',
            data: 
                {
                  'email': 'test@gmail.com'
                },
            success: function(response) {  },
            error: function(response) {  }
        });
```

Servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws    ServletException, IOException {
final String email = request.getParameter("email");
}
```

Any ideas on why I would continue to get null? Any help is appreciated. I learn best by code
samples so please try to include where applicable. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you returning something to the UI?  All I see is you setting an email parameter.

Comment: Sorry @CodeChimp I'm kind of confused on your question. I'm just looking to gather the email parameter. I have a form that just has an email input.

Comment: So, are you saying that your form is posting a null value for email, or are you saying you are expecting some return back, but you are getting null.

Comment: I'm expecting some return back but getting null.

Comment: Well, your doPost() doesn't seem to be returning anything.  I would expect to see something in there like `request.getRequestDispatcher("some.jsp").forward(request,response);` or a `response.getWriter()` followed by some writing of the response.  All your method seems to do is grab the email from the request.